# IB Python API - Histroical Market Data for German Stocks

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

I would like to retrieve and store historical market data for german stocks like Daimler AG.

The code I am using for this is the following:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import inline

class MyWrapper(EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.df = None

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        print("Setting nextValidOrderId: %d", orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        self.data.append(vars(bar));

    def historicalDataUpdate(self, reqId, bar):
        line = vars(bar)
        # pop date and make it the index, add rest to df
        # will overwrite last bar at that same time
        self.df.loc[pd.to_datetime(line.pop('date'))] = line

    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
        print("HistoricalDataEnd. ReqId:", reqId, "from", start, "to", end)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.data)
        self.df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['date'])
        self.df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error. Id: ", reqId, " Code: ", errorCode, " Msg: ", errorString)

    def start(self):
        queryTime = ""

        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "DAI
        contract.secType = 'STK'
        contract.exchange = 'SMART'
        contract.currency = "EUR"
        contract.primaryExchange = "SMART"

        app.reqHistoricalData(1, fx, queryTime, "1 D", "1 min", "MIDPOINT", 0, 1, True, [])


wrap = MyWrapper()
app = EClient(wrap)
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=123)

# I just use this in jupyter so I can interact with df
import threading

threading.Thread(target=app.run).start()

print(wrap.df)
wrap.df.to_csv("myfile.csv")  # save in file
app.disconnect()

wrap.df.close.plot()
```

I always get the error message:
"Error. Id:  1  Code:  162  Msg:  Historical Market Data Service error message:No market data permissions for BATEDE, CHIXDE, DXEDE, EBS, TGHEDE, TRQXDE STK"

I do have a market data subscription for Xetra/Frankfurt and the stock "DAI" is definitely traded there. Why does it say I don't have market data permission? Do I have to specify the subscribed market data exchanges? If so, what is the correct name I have to put in at "contract.exchange"?

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to "European (BATS/Chi-X) Equities" which is free? To get a consolidated feed in some countries requires you to get all subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

IB has a [website](https://misc.interactivebrokers.com/cstools/contract_info/v3.10/index.php) that lets you to search for different securities. The information page for Daimler AG is [here](https://misc.interactivebrokers.com/cstools/contract_info/v3.10/index.php?action=Conid%20Info&wlId=IB&conid=29622935&lang=en&ib_entity=). It looks like the `contract.exchange` property should be set to `IBIS`.

To view or modify trading permissions, open Trader Workstation and go to Account > Account Management Home. Then click the Trading Permissions link in the lower left.